# How to route to new page in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a router which has a link to a product details page, problem is, the application is being displayed in a android `webview` so ... if am viewing a product details page and clicked back, the whole application will exit.

is there a way to make the use go back to the home page ? or I have to implement a back button ?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <div>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            {/* <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={HomePage} /> */}
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Template>
              <Route path="/:id" component={PropertyTemplate} />
            </Template>

          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not neccessary to implement backbutton - just this code make work:

```
 history.goBack()
```

Here is implemented **BackButton** - just add this in common folder in architecture & reuse.

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import ReturnIcon from '../../img/tech/return-white-icon.svg'

const GoBack = ({ history }) => <img src={ReturnIcon} onClick={() => history.goBack()} alt="Go back" />;

export default withRouter(GoBack);
```

Comment: this is what I meant by implementing `back` button, I don't want to do that, I want to use android's back button

Comment: so use this -  history.goBack()

Comment: Of course it's need to - npm i history + importing this library